Seth and Cain take turns picking numbers from 1 to 50. Who wins?
Seth and Cain play a game. They take turns, and on each turn a player chooses a pair of integers from 1 to 50 inclusive. One integer in the pair must be twice the other, and the players cannot choose any integers used previously. The first player who is unable to choose such a pair loses the game. If Seth starts, determine which player, if any, has a winning strategy.

Attribution:  UK Intermediate Mathematical Olympiad Maclaurin paper 2020

Seth and Cain?  Are we to understand one player has already been eliminated?

@DougWarren You are right.  One is no longer able to compete.

@Will.Octagon.Gibson ba dum tss

We could crank out the solution by noting that this game is effectively Dawson's Kayles, an impartial game, and applying the Sprague-Grundy theorem to find the Nim value of the start position.
But, let's instead give an explicit winning strategy.
First, it helps to sort the numbers into chains of doublings, the rows below, where each turn removes two consecutive numbers within a row:
 1  2  4  8 16 32
 3  6 12 24 48
 5 10 20 40
 7 14 28
 9 18 36
11 22 44
13 26
15 30
17 34
19 38
21 42
23 46
25 50

The odd numbers from 27 to 50 are omitted because they can't be used. More generally, any number left without neighbors after removals is useless, and we can imagine it disappears.
Let's show how Seth (the start player) wins by ensuring that an odd number of turns take place, which puts him as the last player to go and so the winner. The 10 rows of length 2 or 3 each take up one turn. The row of length 5 always takes 2 turns -- the first one either leaves a row of 3, or a row of 2 and a useless singleton. So, these always take 12 turns, which doesn't affect the parity.
So, this leaves the rows of length 4 and 6, which might take different numbers of turns depending on which pairs get removed. Seth starts by removing the numbers 1 and 2, now leaving two length-4 rows (4-8-16-32 and 5-10-20-40). Now, whenever Cain moves in one of them, Seth just mirrors it in the other, which makes for an even number of further turns there, odd counting Seth's starting move. So, Seth wins.
